# UIToolbar in UIScrollView fixed with UIViewController as scrolling as subview problem

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitoolbar

i'm having a BIG problem that i don't know how to solve...

my UIToolbar that is supposed to be fixed @ the bottom of the screen , appears scaled thorugh all the screen.

In my case i have:

an UIViewController

with an image scroling with an UIScrollView.

so i need the toolbar on the bottom of the screen but instead , it replaces the image scrolling and ocupies all the screen. This happened when i moved from V2 to V3 of the iphone Xcode..before it was showing ok...

I will briefly explain how i'm initializing the things:
in the h file  UIScrollView *myScroll;
in the .M file i have
UIToolbar *toolbar;

then on the  (void)viewDidLoad {

```
toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 50);
------------------------

myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myImage.frame.size.width, myImage.frame.size.height);

myScroll.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
myScroll.minimumZoomScale = 1;

myScroll.clipsToBounds = YES;
CGRect frame2 = myImage.frame;

frame2.origin.y=frame2.origin.y+40;
myScroll.contentOffset=frame2.origin;



myScroll.delegate = self;

[myScroll addSubview:myImage];  

    [myScroll.superview addSubview:toolbar];
```

so the frame set on the toolbar doesn't work...and it sets itself over the whole screen...

i would prefer not to extend the UIScrollView, because i want to have some buttons that are related to this class functions..

The functionality i want to acomplish is having a zoomable, panable photo and some options, to comment, and vote , and prev. next etc..from the toolbar[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?ef28ce0bb4.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?ef28ce0bb4.jpg)

here's a preview:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use Interface Builder to set up your toolbar.

Just drop a UIToolbar in your window and hook it up to your view controller. Here's how you set up the buttons programmatically, but you could just as easily add them in IB and wire them up there.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                              target:self 
                              action:@selector(insertNewObject)];

    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:addButton];
    self.toolbar.items = items;
}
```

Comment: i will try it, but i'm afraid that it will screw up the Uiscrollview

Comment: I tried it, and it doesn't show the toolbar somehow...only in interface builder....

i'm doing one thing to hide the TAB bar and navbar ...when i show the view...

 [self.mynav.view setNeedsLayout]; 
 [self.mynav setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]; 
 appDelegate.tabBarController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

Comment: It's really hard to debug this without looking at your nib file. Is it possible that your Tabbar is over the top of your Toolbar?